# Effect of Singleton class in case of a Library file

Tags: android

I have a design question on Android.

I have a class which used to register Accelerometer sensor in Andriod. I am passing the SensorEventListener as parameter in the defined function so that user will get the functionality to work on live sensor data or to store it using POJO class.

What will be the effect if I implement a Singleton Design Pattern on that class? Is there any blockage from devlepment side?

Sample Code :

```
public class Accel
{
    private static Accel accelObj;
    private Accel(Context context)
    {

    }
    public static synchronized Accel getInstance(Context context) 
    {
        if (accelObj == null)
        accelObj = new Accel(context);

    return accelObj;
    }
    public registerListener(SensorEventListener listener)
    {
     // To Do
    }
}
```

This class I want to use for application development. Is there any drawback other then slower due to synchronized method for application development?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the same method and could not see any reason for it to be a bad idea for cases where your class only depends on a basic application context.

I found it to be a neat method for relieving my Activities and Fragments of having to hold code logic needed in multiple places across my app.

Things becomes more troublesome if you get to a point where have more objects constructed in this way and they have more complex dependencies. If you need Activity context in some cases, e.g. to show dialogs etc, or you need to have internal dependencies.

In my case I ended up writing a Factory that constructed the objects in the correct order and gave the dependencies as parameters. Though working it became very annoying to maintain. Imagine having a Service that can run in background even though the app is destroyed, now the 'guarentees' that the object has been constructed and reside in memory is once more gone.

The solution for me was to implement [Dagger](http://square.github.io/dagger/)

Using this I can construct the object like this

```
@Singleton
public class Accel
{
    @Inject
    public Accel(@ForApplication Context context)
    {

    }

    public registerListener(SensorEventListener listener)
    {
     // To Do
    }
}
```

Now at any place that I need the Accel object in the app:

```
public {Activity, Fragment, Service} {

    @Inject Accel acc; <- acc is now constructed and ready for use

}
```

This works with multiple dependencies too:

```
@Singleton
public class AnotherModule
{
    @Inject
    public AnotherModule(@ForActivity Context context, Accel acc, ThirdModule thridMod)
    {

    }

    public registerListener(SensorEventListener listener)
    {
     // To Do
    }
}
```

Notice the @ForActivity, this means that this module will not work in a module (as we depend on an Activity context being present)

```
public {Activity, Fragment} {

    @Inject AnotherModule anotherMod; <- anotherModis now constructed and ready for use

}
```

Using Dagger greatly lifted the quality of my code as it removed any redundant and boilerplate code needed to setup the modules.

The price is that it is somewhat difficult to get working at first, at least it was for me. Took a week to learn and apply to ~15k lines of code, so as mentioned earlier. If you only need a single singleton object, then it might be overkill to do this :)

Hope this is helpful to you